# how to refresh fetchedResultsController after persistent store change

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm a weekend warrior when it comes to programming, so I have probably done something wrong...

I have a split view controller, core data, nsfetchedResultsController, all that works great.  I now have an option for the user to create a backup file of the persistentStore.sqlite file.  When the user restores from a backup file, the tableview doesn't reflect any change.  And on top of that, can't make any lasting changes from then on from the tableview add/delete.  When I quit the app and restart it, all the data is there from the back up and all is working well.

How can I force the tableview to get the now new info from the fetched results controller?  Or how do I force the

Here's some scatterings of what I have tried so far without success:

```
MasterViewController.m

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    context = [[OSCDStackManager sharedManager] managedObjectContext];
}

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadFetchedResults) name:OSFilesUpdatedNotification object:nil];

- (void)reloadFetchedResults:(NSNotification*)note {
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
    if (note) {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}


- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

from a manual refresh pulldown on the tableview...

```
-(void) updateTable{
    context = [[OSCDStackManager sharedManager] managedObjectContext];
    NSError *error = nil;
    [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
    //[self.tableView endUpdates];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated  {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}


- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    context = [[OSCDStackManager sharedManager] managedObjectContext];
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    //[NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"cache"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Even though this is an app for my neighbor, I'd hate tell him to kill and restart the app after a back up...

**Solution** ended up being a combination of both answers below,

```
- (void)reloadFetchedResults{
    self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
    [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"cache"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nil out your FRC

```
-(void)reloadData
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    self.fetchedResultsController = nil;

    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
    else
        [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

** EDIT ** in case it's not obvious with the 'self' at the front you'll need somewhere in your class

```
-(NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (!_fetchedResultsController)
    {
        _fetchedResultsController = [NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:aFetchRequest
                                         managedObjectContext:aManagedObjectContext // the main thread MOC
                                           sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
            // addional FRC setup etc.

    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Comment: this finally solved it, but I also needed to delete the cache.

Comment: you had to `nil` out your `NSFetchedResultsController`? I've never had to do that. Deleting the cache was all I had to do.

Comment: This example is also wrong, you're setting `self.fetchedResultsController = nil` but you use it in the next line.

Comment: @Evils I think saying it's wrong is unfair... the question is 'how to refresh fetchedResultsController after persistent store change' nilling out the cache is also ok. but you could have `sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil]'` lazy objects are fairly common... it should be second nature in Obj C and Swift

Comment: In my case none of these things helped. I set the fetchedResultsController to nil, cleared the cache, and reloaded the tableView. But it still ended up calling to the delegate methods once it was time to reload the tableView, and it would still have the serious error. So I ended up having to disable the delegate methods with a boolean check. After reloading the tableView I re-enabled the delegate methods. In the end, I did not have to do any of the other suggestions. This solved my problem after replacing the core data store.

Comment: It's an amazing tip!  I had no idea you had to nil it.  There's no "invalidate" call or similar.  Thanks, @Magoo !

Answer (score 4):

Did you delete the cache?

You need to first set the cache name to the `fetchedResultsController` (notice the `cacheName` argument at the end):

```
_fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:query
                                                                managedObjectContext:context
                                                                  sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                           cacheName:@"CACHE_NAME"];
```

Then delete the cache when you make an update:

```
[NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"CACHE_NAME"];
```

After doing this, load from core data again by doing this:

```
NSError *error;
if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
    // Update to handle the error appropriately.
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error loading data %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    exit(-1);  // Fail
}
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are replacing the sqlite file you are probably best tearing everything down and starting with a fresh managed object context. This is a similar question to deleting the store.